# Как зарефакторить множество return в методе

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, шаблоны-проектирования, typescript

Подскажите паттерны или решения для того чтобы писать лучше
Пример кода

```
class Test{

      private client;
      private concreteMixer;
      constructor(client, concreteMixer){
        this.client = client;
        this.concreteMixer = concreteMixer;
      }

      public method(){
        let form = new Form();
        if(form.isSubmitted()){
          if(form.isValid()){

            let field = form.getField();
            let infoField = this.client.testField(field);
            if(!infoField){
              form.setError('This is not valid field');
              return form;
            }

            let coffee = this.concreteMixer.makeСoffee();
            //two days have passed
            if(!coffee){
              form.setError('I want coffee');
              return form;
            }

            this.concreteMixer.pourInThermosBottle();
            //two days have passed

            return coffee;
          }
        }

        return form;
      }
    }
```

Comment: а что конкретно не нравится?

Comment: @Grundy да говорят что у метода должен быть один return

Comment: кто говорит? Это утверждение как-то аргументируется?

Comment: @Grundy Solid говорит

Comment: Ты уверен, что там написано именно про _один return_?

Comment: @Grundy Вот ссылка на статью по теме https://habrahabr.ru/post/40841/

Comment: Здесь уже тоже были подобные вопросы. Кстати, по приведенной ссылке не увидел связи с SOLID о которой ты упоминал

Comment: Ну и сам метод в принципе странный, почему он всегда возвращает form, кроме одного случая, когда возвращает coffee?

Comment: @Grundy в случае ошибок нужно вернуть объект form в случае успеха coffee (Вообще это на Symfony  обычный экшен обработки формы)